# C++ Clear an Input Buffer

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, input, buffer, getch

As of now, I'm making a program with different screens that use the escape key to exit, but what happens is if I press escape in, lets say the option menu. And then I go into the game, which the game allows escape to exit out, it will automatically leave the game. If that makes sense. :), but, it seems like the escape key floats around in the input buffer, and I tried many ways to clear it but I can't find a way. Here is a part of my code.

```
int Controls()
{
    // Allows us to get a key when pressed
    int Key;
    Key = _getch();

    switch(Key)
    {
    // Number 27
    case KEY_ESCAPE:
        do code...
        break;

    }
    return Key;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing a

```
fflush(stdin);
```

whenever you transition to any new page. It clears the input stream.

Comment: The variable might be persisting from some other part of the code. How are you using the "Key" that you return from the function? Also, try storing the input in a character pointer. Hope this helps.